# Missing logs in django

Tags: django, webfaction

I have a django app on Webfaction, and it seems that logs it is sending do not get written in the log file.

I have the following code:

```
    log.debug('batch, guid: %s' % request.POST['guid'])
    events = request.POST.getlist('logbatch[]')
    for event in events:
        a = event.split(';')
        userlog = UserLog(csq_id=CsqId.objects.get(guid=request.POST['guid']), elementId=a[1], event=a[0], counter=int(a[2]), clientTime=js_time_to_python(int(a[3])))
        userlog.save()
```

In general, logging works and is configured correctly. However, when I look in the database, I can see UserLog objects that are not logged in. As the DB insertion happens after the logging, I am certain that django did log the code. So why is it not in the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Django documentation on logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/). You need to [configure logging in your settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) first, before you start using it. There is also [an example configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#an-example) provided in the documentation.

Comment: Ludwik, thanks for your answer. Logging does generally works in my app - but for this logic, some logs are missing, even though I can see the logic is working.